# Error with casting value returned by sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
string sql =
          "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT testId from TestData where testId=@testId) " +
          "Insert INTO TestData (testId, jsonString) VALUES(@testId, @jsonstring) " +
          "else " +
          "UPDATE TestData SET jsonString=@jsonstring WHERE testId=@testId " +
          "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
```

In order to have a row from `TestData` table wither created if not exists, or updated if it does.

The first time I use this, so when a record does not exist it works fine. If I call the function again though:

```
conn.Open();
newID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

So this time the record already exists, I get a casting error probably when trying to cast to `Int32`.

Is there something wrong with my query, and what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the casting error from C# or from SQL Server?  If from C#, then the problem may be the `NULL` return value.  Do you know if the update is actually taking place?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually believe its from C#, and I can actually confirm that the update is taking place.

Comment: If the row doesn't yet exist, you're simply inserting it - but you're not returning anything. So the return value of `ExecuteScalar` will be NULL - and you cannot convert `NULL` to an int  ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you then want code that is more like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from TestData where testId = @testId) 
BEGIN
    Insert INTO TestData(testId, jsonString)
        VALUES(@testId, @jsonstring);
    SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TestData SET jsonString = @jsonstring WHERE testId = @testId;
    SELECT CAST(id as int) FROM TestData WHERE testId = @testId;
END;
```

I am assuming that some column other than `testId` is the identity column -- say `id`.  In general, you wouldn't be setting the identity column in an `insert` statement.

Also, `scope_identity()` is probably just fine for your purposes.  But the safest way of returning information from new rows is to use the `output` clause (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Error may be because as you already have that testid.scope_identity() will return null as it does made any identity operation.
Use 
SELECT @testId for update .